# sc_spawn and other process [SystemC]

Tags: process, systemc

Can you explain the difference between sc_spawn and another process (SC_METHOD, SC_THREAD, SC_CTHREAD )?

Thanks all.
Hook

Answer (score 4):

To understand this, you have to get an idea of the phases of elaboration and simulation of SystemC first. The phases of elaboration and simulation shall run in the following sequence (from [IEEE Std 1666-2011](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1666-2011.html):

> 1. Elaboration—Construction of the module hierarchy
> 2. Elaboration—Callbacks to function `before_end_of_elaboration`
> 3. Elaboration—Callbacks to function `end_of_elaboration`
> 4. Simulation—Callbacks to function `start_of_simulation`
> 5. Simulation—Initialization phase
> 6. Simulation—Evaluation, update, delta notification, and timed notification phases   (repeated)
> 7. Simulation—Callbacks to function `end_of_simulation`
> 8. Simulation—Destruction of the module hierarchy

Processes are objects derived from `sc_object` and are created by calling `SC_METHOD`, `SC_THREAD`, `SC_CTHREAD`, or the `sc_spawn` function.

If a process is created created during elaboration (1.) or the `before_end_of_elaboration` (2.) it is a *static process*. If it is created during the the `end_of_elaboration` (3.) callback or during simulation, it is a *dynamic process*.

A process instance created by the `SC_METHOD`, `SC_THREAD`, or `SC_CTHREAD` macro is an *unspawned process instances* and is typically a static process. *Spawned process instances* are processes created by calling `sc_spawn`. Typically, they are dynamic processes, but can be static if `sc_spawn` is called before the `end_of_elaboration` phase.

This means, to wrap this up in simple words, that `sc_spawn` enables you to dynamically add processes *during* simulation. For example: there can be cases where you only need a certain process, if a certain condition during your simulation becomes true.

Now let's take a look where the processes spawn during the simulation. The actual simulation of SystemC (6.) consists of these phases:

> 1. Initialization Phase—Execute all processes (except SC_CTHREADS) in an unspecified order.
> 2. Evaluation Phase—Select a process that is ready to run and resume its execution. This may cause immediate event notifications to occur, which may result in additional processes being made ready to run in this same phase. Repeat, as long as there are still processes ready to run.
> 3. Update Phase—Execute any pending calls to update() resulting from request_uptdate() calls made in step 1 or 2.
> 4. Delta notification phase—If there are pending delta notifications (result from calls to notify()), determine which processes are ready to run due to the delayed notifications and go to step 2.
> 5. Timed notification phase—If pending timed notifications or time-outs exist:
>
>    1. advance simulation time to the time of the earliest pending timed notification or time-out;
>    2. determine which process instances are sensitive to the events notified and time-outs lapsing at this precise time;
>    3. add all such process instances to the set of runnable processes;
>    4. If no pending timed notifications or time-outs exist → end of simulation. Otherwise, go to evaluation phase.

If `sc_spawn` is called to create a spawned process instance, the new process will be added to the set of runnable processes (except if `dont_initialize` is called). If `sc_spawn` is called during the evaluation phase, it shall be runnable in the current evaluation phase (2.). If it is called during the update phase (3.), it shall be runnable in the next evaluation phase.

If `sc_spawn` is called during elaboration, the spawned process will be a child of the module instance which calls `sc_spawn`. If it is called during simulation, it will be a child of the process that called the function `sc_spawn`. You may call `sc_spawn` from a method process (`SC_METHOD`), a thread process (`SC_THREAD`), or a clocked thread process (`SC_CTHREAD`).

[This tutorial](https://sclive.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/systemc-tutorial-threads-methods-and-sc_spawn/) shows the difference between implementing processes through `SC_METHOD` and `SC_THREAD`, and `sc_spawn`.